# How to fix Django AWS EC2 Gunicorn ExecStart ExecStop end error?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to point my AWS Route 53 Domain to my EC2 IPv4 Public IP for my Django app, but I'm running into some gunicorn issues. The ***strange thing*** is that I am getting a successful nginx configuration messages, but yet it doesn't work. I've already created a record set on Route 53.

Error:
**gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.**

**Settings.py:**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['175.228.35.250', 'myapp.com']
```

**gunicorn.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_app
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app.sock my_app.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Nginx Code:**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 175.228.35.250 my_app.com www.my_app.com;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
      root /home/ubuntu/my_app;
  }
  location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/my_app/my_app.sock;
  }
}
```

**Nginx Test is successful but yet app won't run:**

```
ubuntu@ip-175-228-35-250:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: Don't post code as links to files. But your service file appears to be an nginx config file, instead of a systemd one.

Comment: Oh sorry! Please see updated code put into the post. I was trying to make it easy for everyone with the links so they wouldn't have to scroll forever. The systemctl error is long so I kept that as link.

Comment: Are you sure that is now the actual service file? The error message is complaining about lines up to 12, but the file you've posted only has 10 lines.

Comment: Go to: 174.129.45.220. It is still not working. Thank you for responding. The code that is posted now is what is live right now."/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service" 10L, 325C "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone that cares. I logged into the system and check it. Attempted to run gunicorn manually and it gives us a different error! It seem to be confusion between Gunicorn and using the venv. I reset the venv and reinstalled the requirements. System now attempts to load the application correctly. Turned on debugging, so PandaNinja can debug the remaining issue due the application now crashing.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
    import(module)
ImportError: No module named travel_buddy.wsgi
```